# How to convert cv::Mat type from CV_16UC1 to CV_8UC1

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a cv::Mat image of type CV_16UC1 and I need it in CV_8UC1, so I can run cv::integral on it. I am not worried about overflow during the conversion - essentially I just want to bulk convert the image from unsigned short to unsigned char.

I asked elsewhere and someone suggested [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor), but I don't know what conversion code to use.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using Mat::convertTo? [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#void%20Mat%3a%3aconvertTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20int%20rtype,%20double%20alpha,%20double%20beta%29%20const)

A quick example: (not sure if you need scalefactor though, since I haven't tried)

Your16Image.convertTo(outputImage, CV_8UC1, scalefactor)

Comment: This worked for me - but turns out I needed cv::threshold as well because I want to input a binary image into cv::integral. Noted in case anyone has a similar problem. cv::threshold(m, binary, 0, 1, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

Comment: did you use scale factor? (Can you maybe post all steps...?). thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cv::convertScaleAbs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=convertscaleabs#cv.ConvertScaleAbs) which directly set your output matrix to unsigned char.